# In a Webpage, I have few buttons with same id and same field name, only the value is different. How to find these elements using selenium?

Tags: user-interface, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html, ui-automation

I have four submit buttons in my page.

The Id and name of all the four submits are same, only the value is different.

How to find the elements using selenium driver? (Id-same, name-same)

Comment: Please post the HTML code snippet for the submit buttons.

Comment: this is a very good question, but poorly written.  please provide code of what you have tried, and do exactly what @RupeshShinde  and provide surrounding HTML of all of the elements.. then we can help you!

Comment: Check out peetya's answer. XPath is an absolute path directly to what element/elements you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*button[@value='the value what are you looking for']");
```